# I get an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)"

Tags: android, notepad++, postman

[this is the error that occurred when I am debugging the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HucHf.jpg)

Below is the code where the **ERROR** occured :

```
public function does_user_exist($email,$password)
{
$query = "Select * from users where email = '$email' and password='$password'";
**$result = mysqli_query(this -> connection, $query);**
```

Answer (score 1):

> $result = mysqli_query(this -> connection, $query)

in PHP it's `$this`, not `this`. Fix your code to look like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
```

Without `$` it means constant, and since only scalar data can be constant, using `->` with constant is syntactically invalid, hence the error you facing.